# Variable number of entries to a single input argument

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function that can call varying distribution functions, depending on what the user gives as an Input. The following example is not from the code I am working on right now, but a simple, reproducible one:

```
fun <- function(dist, params){
  rdist <- get(paste("r", dist, sep=""), mode="function")
  return(rdist(n = 1, params))
}
```

But when I run the function using the following syntax, an obviously unwanted result appears:

```
> fun("norm", c(mean=1, sd=0))
[1] 1.713108
```

What does work is:

```
fun2 <- function(dist, params){
  rdist <- get(paste("r", dist, sep=""), mode="function")
  return(rdist(n = 1, params[1], params[2]))
}
> fun2("norm", c(mean=1, sd=0))
[1] 1
```

Is there a simple way to get the code in the former example to run like the latter?

Comment: Would `switch` be acceptable? You would have to write a line for every distribution, but you have a lot of power over which parameters are passed (for instance, normal and weibull distributions use different argument names).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for :

```
do.call("rnorm", list(n=1,mean=1, sd=0))
```

you can wrap this in a function :

```
fun_dist <- function(dist="norm",...){
  rdist <- paste("r", dist, sep="")
  do.call(rdist, list(n=1,...))
}
```

Then you call it :

```
 fun_dist(mean=1, sd=0)
[1] 1

fun_dist('norm',mean=1, sd=0)
[1] 1
```

### EDIT

The Op is looking for a solution where it give the parameters grouped in a single argument params.

```
fun_dist <- function(dist="norm",params){
  rdist <- paste("r", dist, sep="")
  do.call(rdist, as.list(c(n=1,params)))
}

fun_dist('norm',c(mean=1, sd=0))
```

Comment: Sorry for unaccepting your answer, but I think it will not work for my purpose. I am optimizing a function over its parameters, for which I explicitly need the params input.
A solution I am looking for would allow me to take the params vector c(mean = 1, sd = 0) and find some way of "unc'ing" it, and enter each element into the function.

Sorry if I was not clear on this in my initial question.

Comment: I found a solution, that is based on your answer, which yields the wanted result:
`fun <- function(dist, params){rdist <- get(paste("r", dist, sep=""), mode="function"); do.call(rnorm, lapply(c(n=1, params), function(x){x}));}`